# Getting document's image scanned with panini vision x device

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a function (or functions) in C# to retrieve the image (front and back) of a check scanned with Panini vision x device and then store it in disk.

Currently, the device is passing the document in the track and I don't know which function to call to capture the check side's images.

Thank you.

Until now, i couldn't try any thing.